# python sshtunnel not starting server given credentials

Tags: python, mysql, mariadb, ssh-tunnel, mysql-connector-python

So I'm trying to get `mysql-connector-python` to work with `sshtunnel`

```
with SSHTunnelForwarder(('192.168.0.1', 22), ssh_username='pi', ssh_password='*********', remote_bind_address=('localhost', 3306)) as tunnel:
    tunnel.start()
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",
                                   user='Mashu',
                                   password='*******',
                                   port=tunnel.local_bind_port,
                                   db='mysql')

print(mydb)
cur = mydb.cursor()
cur.execute('USE mysql')
print(cur.execute('SELECT * FROM user'))
```

And it seems to execute smoothly, but when I want to create cursor it says

```
mysql.connector.errors.OperationalError: MySQL Connection not available.
```

I investigated it further and found out that values connected to local binding, so `local_bind_address`, `local_bind_host`, etc. are all set to errors, saying:

```
Server is not started. Please .start() first!
```

Even though I do have `tunnel.start()` in my code 
I did check, and my server is visible for other programs (f.e. DataGrip), I have no idea where the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a context manager with `with SSHTunnelForwarder`, meaning that it will close the connection when it exits the scope. Putting the `cur = mydb.cursor` inside the context manager scope will solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can remove the context manager but remember to close the tunnel since you are explicitly starting it.

```js
tunnel = get_ssh_tunnel(host, int(port), ssh_config)
                tunnel.start()
                conn = #connection settings
                # do stuff
                tunnel.close()
                conn.close()
```